# Limit Request from client systems using htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Recently i found 80% of total visits to my website is originated from a single IP. Is it possible to set the maximum allowed requests to my website using php or htaccess . Or any other suggestions . Also i need to know whether any way to block requestes generated through automated scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

This is best handled with Apache directly.

You can block requests based on patterns that bots exhibit, however this can lead to false positives that lose you real traffic. What I suggest is just denying the offending IP address and move on.

I would recommend either blocking the IP address in your hosts.deny or the Virtual Host file for your Apache Configureation (if you are using VHosts, otherwise, just in the Apache config directly, wherever the root directory is specified.)

If you want to block connections by IP per time I recommend MOD QoS for Apache.
http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/

I hear it is somewhat difficult to set up, but worth it for guiding traffic when needed.